# Ternary operator in Yaml

Tags: yaml, snakeyaml

How do I use ternary operator in a yaml file for the snakeparser to parse it

I use groovy to parse the expression and the !e tag helps me in doing so.
now when i use ternary operator the parser fails.

> name : abc
>
> value : !e 5>3 ? true : false

How do I get the parser to actually parse the expression instead of it assuming that the colon in ternary operator in the mapping colon used by yaml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use any of the following:

Double-quoted scalar (may contain escape sequences):

```
value: !e "5>3 ? true : false"
```

Single-quoted scalar (may not contain escape sequences):

```
value: !e '5>3 ? true : false'
```

Folded block scalar (the `-` removes the trailing newline):

```
value: !e >-
  5>3 ? true : false
```

Literal block scalar (as above):

```
value: !e |-
  5>3 ? true : false
```